# Prevent logged out users from accessing url links which are available for logged in users

Tags: php

I have done a login page by using session variable to store username based on which users are made to login, I would like to know whether it is possible to make url links which are accessible only for the logged in users, but the url links should not be available to users who are not logged in , for example a person who is logged in , if he tries to copy the url and give it to another person and if that person pastes the url in his address bar without logging in he should redirected to a login page or some message should be displayed saying that he needs to be logged in inorder to view that particular url link .

I have searched in google regarding this , not able to find any solution.

**EDIT **
Actually the link  is a https page whose url needs to be hidden , similar to the way we hide the path of pdf which are used for downloading using header .

For Example i make a php page where if the username is in session and he clicks a link he will be redirected to this link page but he cannot see the url .

Thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's easier if you're using a framework like CakePHP but I'm sure you can do it in straight PHP too.

Comment: You can definitely do this.  The URLs will need to be handled by PHP, of course.  Have your code send an error if it doesn't see `$_SESSION['username']` set (or whatever you've called it).  Give it a try, then post some code if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a session variable when login is successful.

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Then at the start of every page use `session_start()`

Immediately after that check

`if(! isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { /* redirect to login page */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the "URL Links" are to PHP pages, at the top of each page simply verify that the web browser requesting the page has established a valid session.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggeduser']){
echo "Welcome";
}
else{
echo "Unauthorized User";
//redirect user to login page
}

?>
```